# How to implement custom 'time out' for https request?

Tags: ruby, timeout

I have working code that gets data over https (below). In fact it runs some test through php. I used standard timeout that works fine. Now while "waiting" for server response I need to implement timer. Because in some cases the test won't finish - the php code will not finish - the ruby time out works ok. So I need to kill some process to capture the error in the existing https session.

**How can I implement my own time out for https request on top of existing time out?**

The existing timeout will be always greater than custom timeout. eg existing timeout is 10mins and the custom will be 5 mins.

```
uri = URI.parse(url)
start = Time.new
http_read_timeout=60*10

connection = Net::HTTP.new(uri.host, 443)
connection.use_ssl = true
begin   
        response = connection.start() do |http|
            http.open_timeout =  50
            http.read_timeout = http_read_timeout
            http.request_get(uri.request_uri)
            # here I need to place a code that is triggered 
            # in case of custom timeout is reached
        end
rescue Timeout::Error
#  "Connection failed
    time_out_message ="security time out - after #{http_read_timeout} sec"
return time_out_message         

end

puts "finished"
```

Comment: Why the test will not finish if you've set the timeouts for http connection open_timeout and read_timeout?

Comment: The php code will not finish - the ruby time out works ok. I need to detect that 'test' won't finish then kill a process and that will cause the test to finish with error message. That's why I need this 'custom timeout' to capture the error message. When the ruby's timeout is used the error message is not captured because the test hasn't finished.

Comment: PHP code is irrelevant for my question. It could be any code. The code  that runs the text is ok but the code that the test is testing my have a bug. That's the whole purpose of this exercise find a bug. And it would make my life easier if I can capture the error message. The testing is done overnight so next morning I have to reproduce the test scenario in hand to get the error.

Comment: On the other hand php code could be written the way that it would force the error message to be outputted. I asked our developers for modification but it won't happen any soon. So either I find my own solution or ... in that light the php code is irrelevant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't get it. What does your custom timeout do? You are making an HTTP request...it either returns or times out.

You're already setting the timeout value. Your code can't reach into the future & tell you what the external code would eventually return, if it did...so what do you want it to do, exactly?

But if you really just need an external Timeout wrapper, you can use Timeout::Timeout. Like this:

```
require 'timeout'
Timeout::timeout(your_timeout_period) do
  run_some_code
rescue => err
  do_something_with err
  # and maybe the below?
  raise
end
```

Comment: I need to find out if the HTTP request is taking too long. Longer than my 'custom time-out'. If yes then I need to execute some code that 'releases' the php process and then HTTP successfully finishes.

Comment: The existing timeout will be always greater than custom timeout. eg existing timeout is 10mins and the custom will be 5 mins.

Comment: You'd just put your HTTP code inside my block. If all the code you have here were placed inside a method called run_some_code, it'd work fine :) ...except for doing something with the error, anyway.

Comment: Hmmm, I need the HTTP request NOT to be closed. It looks that I need a timer not timeout....Probably I wasn't so clear at what I need. Would your code stop the HTTP request?

Comment: Oh. Then you could spawn a new thread for the http request. Or if something in there blocks, fork a new process.

Comment: And then put your Timer into the original thread. If you need help, email me & I'll edit the answer to show you what I mean (on a bus right now).

Comment: I sent you an email (thank your for offering the help) and created new question : http://stackoverflow.com/q/10729212/250422