# How to implement timer that runs independently along with http request?

Tags: ruby, multithreading

I have a ruby code that triggers php script over https.

*Use case:* The php script usually finishes in 5 minutes so I have set up time out for https request after 10 minutes. **I need a timer that would trigger code after let's say 7 minutes after the https request started.**

I was thinking of using thread that I created just before I initiate https request. I am not sure if this the correct way to approach this. Maybe there is not need to use threads at all. I am using ruby 1.8.7 (2010-08-16 patchlevel 302) [i386-mingw32]. Also I don't now if I can 'kill' the thread on successful finish of https request.

```
uri = URI.parse(url)
start = Time.new
http_read_timeout=60*10

connection = Net::HTTP.new(uri.host, 443)
connection.use_ssl = true
begin   
        response = connection.start() do |http|
            http.open_timeout =  50
            http.read_timeout = http_read_timeout
            http.request_get(uri.request_uri)
            # here I need to place a code that is triggered 
            # in case of custom timeout is reached
        end
rescue Timeout::Error
#  "Connection failed
    time_out_message ="security time out - after #{http_read_timeout} sec"
return time_out_message         

end

puts "finished"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The basic structure could be like this:

```
seconds_timer = MyDelay
counter = 0

test_thread = Thread.new do
  run_http_php_test
end

while test_thread.alive?
 counter += 1
 if counter > seconds_timer
   handle_custom_timeout_somehow       
   # if you want to halt run_http_php_test: 
   test_thread.kill if test_thread.alive?
   # otherwise:
   break
 end
 sleep 1
end
# the below doesn't apply if you kill the run_http_php_test thread
test_thread.join if test_thread.alive?
```

...but of course you could change that `sleep 1` to whatever polling interval you like. Polling is nicer than just forcing your original thread to sleep, because the code will finish faster if `run_http_php_test` is done before you hit your custom timeout value.

Most or all of your code above can be in the run_http_php_test method, or inserted directly...whichever you'd prefer.

Comment: Works perfectly. Exactly what I needed. Finished POC and going to implement it in my code. I think you are missing `end` for if and `seconds_timer` is not used anywhere in your code.

Comment: One more question. What happens if I don't use `test_thread.join if test_thread.alive?`? Would the thread work? Would it finish?

Comment: Yup, couple of typos. If you don't call test_thread.join, the calling thread will exit. Normally I'd say the second thread will also terminate (if it's still running), but given that it's calling code on a server, I don't know what would happen on that end.

Comment: The one running `run_http_php_test`. Also known as `test_thread`. If the calling thread exits, it will too. So the line calling `test_thread.join` prevents that, if needed.

Answer (score 1):

ruby 1.9.3 implements timeout module that has a timeout function. [you can see it here](http://apidock.com/ruby/Timeout/timeout). if you scroll down you can click show source and see the definition for timeout method. you can copy it if you dont want to upgrade to ruby 1.9.3 (I recommend upgrade since 1.8.7 is very slow compared to 1.9.3)

Comment: You're right about timeout...but it doesn't do what he wanted. He didn't want the original thread to time out and stop executing after 7 minutes--it was supposed to continue regardless. He just wanted a way to know if/when it took that long so he could handle the situation.